# How would I go about allowing users to create surveys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Iv'e gotten myself into a bit of a brain mess up these past two days. I'd like to be able to allow my users to create a campaign (same concept as surveys), it will allow them to request certain data they wish such as an email address. This will then allow the person completing the form to proceed and receive a download link after entering an email. The email entered should be stored for the person who created the campaign to view.

Iv'e taken the approach with nested forms, however I ran into the trouble of allowing emails to be entered and saved for the campaign creator to view.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**campaign.rb model**

`class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :queries
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :queries
end`

**query.rb model**

`class Query < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :campaign
  has_many :results
end`

**result.rb model**

`class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :email, :query_id
  belongs_to :query
end`

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "campaigns", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "title"
t.text     "description"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
 end

  add_index "campaigns", ["user_id"], name: "index_campaigns_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "queries", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "campaign_id"
t.text     "content"
t.string   "email"
t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
end

  add_index "queries", ["campaign_id"], name: "index_queries_on_campaign_id", using: :btree

  create_table "results", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "query_id"
t.text     "content"
t.string   "email"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

  add_index "results", ["query_id"], name: "index_results_on_query_id", using: :btree
```

**Part of campaign_controller.rb**

```
  private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_campaign
  @campaign = Campaign.find(params[:id])
end

def campaign_params
  params.require(:campaign).permit(:title, :description, :queries_attributes)
end

def query_params
  params.require(:query).permit(:content, :email, :campaign_id)
end
```

Comment: It's difficult to help you without seeing your code. A statement of general difficulties without the specifics is just begging to have your question closed.

Comment: Right, well the question still stands whether the approach would be best with nested forms or by another means. But I will update this post with the code I have so far :)